# How can we have column in oracle whose data is dependent on other column from other table and should honour all the updates on dependent table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, derived-column

Let's say I have two tables table A and table B and they have one to many relation.

### Table A

col1 | Col2

### Table B

Col1 | Col3

Now I want to have a Col4 in Table A such that if any row of Col3  is true for a given Col1 value, then i want Col4 in Table A to be set as true else false.

All the updates that happend on Table B should always update my Col4 values in Table A.

Is this achievable thing by using any oracle/PL-SQL features?

Comment: Is it possible?  Sure.  But you'd be far better served with a different approach.  Either do the calculation in a view or create a materialized view that is 1:1 with A and does a refresh on commit to do the calculation when something changes in B.  If you need to persist that calculation, it's much more likely that Oracle's built-in MV refresh logic will cause fewer problems than a bunch of manually coded triggers.

Comment: I fully agree with @JustinCave. A materialized view will be much better than using a set of  manually coding triggers. Better, faster and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Use an on `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` [trigger](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_triggers.htm)

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_tables
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  OF col1
  ON tableA
BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO tableB(col1) VALUES :NEW.col1
END;
```